# weak lower semicontinuity of some functionals.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Let $(\nu_{j} - \phi)$ be is a bounded sequence in $W^{1,p}_{0}(\Omega)$. By reflexivity, there is a function $u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ such that, up to a subsequence
$$ \nu_{j} \rightarrow u \ \mbox{weakly} \ \mbox{in} \ W^{1,p}(\Omega), \nu_{j} \rightarrow u \mbox{in} \ L^{p}(\Omega), \nu_{j} \rightarrow u \ \mbox{a.e in} \ \Omega.$$

I know that from lower semicontiuity of norms we obtain
$$ \int_{\Omega} | \nabla u |^{p} dx \le \liminf_{j} \int_{\Omega} | \nabla  \nu_{j} |^{p} dx. $$ 
But I don't undertand  it. If I had $\nabla u(x) \rightarrow \nabla \nu_{j}(x)$ I could use Fatou's lemma.  I would like to know this in the hope of showing
\begin{equation}
\int_{\Omega} \dfrac{1}{2} \langle A(x) \nabla u(x), \nabla u(x)\rangle \le \liminf_{j} \int_{\Omega} \dfrac{1}{2} \langle A(x) \nabla u_j(x), \nabla u_j(x)\rangle
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
\int_{\{u>0\}} \dfrac{1}{2} \langle A(x) \nabla u(x), \nabla u(x)\rangle \le \liminf_{j} \int_{\{u_j >0\}} \dfrac{1}{2} \langle A(x) \nabla u_j(x), \nabla u_j(x)\rangle
\end{equation}
where $A$ is a continuous matrix.

Comment: The first ynequality holds because the functional is strong continuous  in $L^{p}$ and convex.